# Which peer-to-peer technologies are used to sync blocks in a blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core

I searched a lot about it but didn't found out anything. I want to know about the technologies used in block syncing and the algorithms.

Comment: That's a bit broad. Do you mean what kind of protocol is used, or how nodes balance bandwidth across nodes, or how validation of the received blocks works?

Comment: Yes! I mean the protocol.